# Using super with a class method

Tags: python, class, object, super, class-method

I'm trying to learn the super() function in Python.

I thought I had a grasp of it until I came over this example (2.6) and found myself stuck.

[http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html#super-with-classmethod-example](https://web.archive.org/web/20170820065901/http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html#super-with-classmethod-example)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 9, in do_something
    do_something = classmethod(do_something)
TypeError: unbound method do_something() must be called with B instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
>>>
```

It wasn't what I expected when I read this line right before the example:

> If we're using a class method, we don't have an instance to call super with. Fortunately for us, super works even with a type as the second argument. --- The type can be passed directly to super as shown below.

Which is exactly what Python tells me is not possible by saying that do_something() should be called with an instance of B.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a base class's classmethod in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269217/calling-a-base-classs-classmethod-in-python)

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Sometimes texts have to be read more for the flavor of the idea rather than for the details. This is one of those cases.

In the [linked page](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html#a-super-solution), Examples 2.5, 2.6 and 2.7 should all use one method, `do_your_stuff`. (That is, `do_something` should be changed to `do_your_stuff`.)

In addition, as [Ned Deily pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1817242/190597), `A.do_your_stuff` has to be a class method.

```
class A(object):
    @classmethod
    def do_your_stuff(cls):
        print 'This is A'

class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def do_your_stuff(cls):
        super(B, cls).do_your_stuff()

B.do_your_stuff()
```

`super(B, cls).do_your_stuff`
returns a *bound* method (see [footnote 2](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html#a-super-solution)).  Since  `cls` was passed as the second argument to `super()`, it is `cls` that gets bound to the returned method. In other words, `cls` gets passed as the first argument to the method `do_your_stuff()` of class A.

To reiterate: `super(B, cls).do_your_stuff()` causes `A`'s `do_your_stuff` method to be
called with `cls` passed as the first argument. In order for that to work, `A`'s
`do_your_stuff` has to be a class method. The linked page doesn't mention that,
but that is definitively the case.

PS. `do_something = classmethod(do_something)` is the old way of making a classmethod.
The new(er) way is to use the @classmethod decorator.

---

Note that `super(B, cls)` can not be replaced by `super(cls, cls)`. Doing so could lead to infinite loops. For example,

```
class A(object):
    @classmethod
    def do_your_stuff(cls):
        print('This is A')

class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def do_your_stuff(cls):
        print('This is B')
        # super(B, cls).do_your_stuff()  # CORRECT
        super(cls, cls).do_your_stuff()  # WRONG

class C(B):
    @classmethod
    def do_your_stuff(cls):
        print('This is C')
        # super(C, cls).do_your_stuff()  # CORRECT
        super(cls, cls).do_your_stuff()  # WRONG

C.do_your_stuff()
```

will raise `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`.

If `cls` is `C`, then `super(cls, cls)` searches `C.mro()` for the class that comes after `C`.

```
In [161]: C.mro()
Out[161]: [__main__.C, __main__.B, __main__.A, object]
```

Since that class is `B`, when `cls` is `C`, `super(cls, cls).do_your_stuff()` **always** calls `B.do_your_stuff`. Since `super(cls, cls).do_your_stuff()` is called inside `B.do_your_stuff`, you end up calling `B.do_your_stuff` in an infinite loop.

In Python3, the [0-argument form of `super`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) was added so `super(B, cls)` could be replaced by `super()`, and Python3 will figure out from context that `super()` in the definition of `class B` should be equivalent to `super(B, cls)`.

But in no circumstance is `super(cls, cls)` (or for similar reasons, `super(type(self), self)`) ever correct.

Comment: Are there pitfalls in using super(cls, cls)?

Comment: @GeorgeMoutsopoulos: `super(cls, cls)` is almost certainly a mistake. I've edited the post above to explain why.

Answer (score 70):

In Python 3, you can skip specifying arguments for `super`,

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    def f(cls):
        return "A's f was called."

class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def f(cls):
        return super().f()

assert B.f() == "A's f was called."
```

Comment: This answer could be moved to another question if this particular question is dealing with Python 2 specifically (it's hard to tell since the linked website, CafePy, is no longer available).

Comment: It's not working for me in a project of mine.  It is giving `RuntimeError: super(): no arguments`

Answer (score 4):

I've updated the article to make it a bit clearer: [Python Attributes and Methods # Super](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html#a-super-solution)

Your example using classmethod above shows what a class method is - it passes the class itself instead of the instance as the first parameter. But you don't even need an instance to call the method, for e.g.:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     @classmethod
...     def foo(cls):
...         print cls
... 
>>> A.foo() # note this is called directly on the class
<class '__main__.A'>
```

Answer (score 2):

The example from the web page seems to work as published.  Did you create a `do_something` method for the superclass as well but not make it into a classmethod?  Something like this will give you that error:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def do_something(cls):
...         print cls
... #   do_something = classmethod(do_something)
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     def do_something(cls):
...         super(B, cls).do_something()
...     do_something = classmethod(do_something)
... 
>>> B().do_something()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in do_something
TypeError: unbound method do_something() must be called with B instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Comment: No, my A class looks like this:

class A(object):
    def do_your_stuff(self):
        print "this is A"

Is it necessary to have "class A" as you posted it?
(with do_something = classmethod(do_something)) ?

I feel like the document didn't tell anything about this ..

Comment: The whole point of the `super` call in the B do_something method is to call a method of that name in one of its superclasses.  If there isn't one in A (or in Object), the B().do_something() call fails with `super object has no attribute do_something`.  ~unutbu rightly points out that the example in the document is faulty.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've understood the point now thanks to this beatiful site and lovely community.

If you don't mind please correct me if I'm wrong on classmethods (which I am now trying to understand fully):

```
# EXAMPLE #1
>>> class A(object):
...     def foo(cls):
...             print cls
...     foo = classmethod(foo)
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.foo()
# THIS IS THE CLASS ITSELF (__class__)
class '__main__.A'

# EXAMPLE #2
# SAME AS ABOVE (With new @decorator)
>>> class A(object):
...     @classmethod
...     def foo(cls):
...             print cls
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.foo()
class '__main__.A'

# EXAMPLE #3
>>> class B(object):
...     def foo(self):
...             print self
... 
>>> b = B()
>>> b.foo()
# THIS IS THE INSTANCE WITH ADDRESS (self)
__main__.B object at 0xb747a8ec
>>>
```

I hope this illustration shows ..

Comment: For an explanation of classmethods, perhaps you'll find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669445/what-is-the-difference-between-a-static-method-and-class-method-in-python/1669524#1669524