# super function called inside a method in python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, super

I was trying my hands on super function, below is the code i was executing.

```
class scene(object):
    def enter(self):
        print "a vllan s n your way. what you'll do?"

class centralcorrdor(scene):
    print "startng pont of the game."
    super(centralcorrdor,self).enter()


a = centralcorrdor()
```

however this gives error.

```
class centralcorrdor(scene):
File "game.py", line 8, in centralcorrdor
super(centralcorrdor,self).enter()

NameError: name 'centralcorrdor' is not defined
```

And this does not.

```
class scene(object):
    def enter(self):
        print "a vllan s n your way. what you'll do?"

class centralcorrdor(scene):
    #print "startng pont of the game."
    def func(self):
        super(centralcorrdor,self).enter()
    #scene.enter()

a = centralcorrdor()
a.func()
```

Can someone tell why? Is it that super has be called from inside a method in child class?

Comment: You can format lines of code in your post by selecting the block of code and clicking the button with curly braces.

Comment: You seem confused about how classes work. Why would you call super -
 or print - outside of a method?

Comment: Also, is the `i` key on your keyboard broken? There are seven missing `i`s in that code.

Comment: Yes daniel I just started learning python. So in order to use super it should always be under some method

Comment: yes the 'i' key is not working. :(

Answer (score 0):

You must use the super within a method. For more information you can consult:
[python-programming](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/super) or [using-super-with-a-class-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817183/using-super-with-a-class-method)
I hope this help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

`super` is actually a proxy to your base classes. There is class proxy (defined in a static or a class method) and instance proxy (defined in an instance method).

Your `super(centralcorrdor,self).enter()` statement pass self as the object argument, and if you check `enter` signature is `self`. So, you have to call it on an **instance object**, not in a class method.

In general, you would call `super(class, object)` most of the time.