# unittest.TestCase setUpClass override and inheritance

Tags: python, python-unittest

As can be seen in the following example, I've defined a `BaseClass` for all tests, each test case class inherits the base class.

Both classes needs to perform a one time initialization, when `test_vehicles.py` is executed, I need to make sure that `setUpClass` of the base class is invoked as well, not sure how to achieve that where `@classmethod` is in play.

```
# base.py
import unittest

class BaseClass(unittest.TestCase):
   @classmethod
   def setUpClass(cls):
       # initialize stuff 
       cls.app = app
```

---

```
# test_vehicles.py
class VehiclesTestCase(BaseClass):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # initialize stuff 
        cls.vehicle_id = '123'

    def test_get_vehicle(self):
       resp = self.app.get(self.vehicle_id)
       self.assertEqual(resp, True)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar question [Using super with a class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817183/using-super-with-a-class-method). More information yoou can get also from https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super.

Solution: use super function and bound to the class

```
# test_vehicles.py
class VehiclesTestCase(BaseClass):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(VehiclesTestCase, cls).setUpClass()
        cls.vehicle_id = '123'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `super` method in the inherited classes' `setUpClass` to access the `setUpClass` of `BaseClass`:

```
super().setUpClass()
```

If you don't want to call `super` in each child class, just create an abstract method in `BaseClass` and call it in `setUpClass` of `BaseClass`. `VehiclesTestCase` now has to implement this abstract method:

```
class BaseClass(unittest.TestCase):
   @classmethod
   def setUpClass(cls):
       # initialize stuff 
       cls.app = app

   @classmethod
   def _setUpChild(cls):
       raise NotImplementedError


class VehiclesTestCase(BaseClass):

    @classmethod
    def _setUpChild(cls):
        # initialize stuff 
        cls.vehicle_id = '123'

    def test_get_vehicle(self):
       resp = self.app.get(self.vehicle_id)
       self.assertEqual(resp, True)
```

I would also recommend that `BaseClass` is not a `TestCase` if it cannot run by itself. It would always show up in your test report although it has no tests. You can instead use multi-inheritance:

```
class BaseClass:
   # Stuff

class VehiclesTestCase(BaseClass, unittest.TestCase):
   # Stuff
```

The order of inheritance is important. Method lookup is done from left to right. This means that `BaseClass.setUpClass` overrides the `setUpClass` of `TestCase`.