# __init__ in overridden classmethod

Tags: python, class-method

I have a small class hierarchy with similar methods and `__init__()`, but slightly different static (class) `read()` methods. Specifically will the child class need to prepare the file name a bit before reading (but the reading itself is the same):

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, pars):
        self.pars = pars

    @classmethod
    def read(cls, fname):
        pars = some_method_to_read_the_file(fname)
        return cls(pars)


class Bar(Foo):
    @classmethod
    def read(cls, fname):
        fname0 = somehow_prepare_filename(fname)
        return cls.__base__.read(fname0)
```

The problem here is that `Bar.read(…)` returns a **Foo** object, not a **Bar** object. How can I change the code so that an object of the correct class is returned?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does 'super' do in Python? - difference between super().\_\_init\_\_() and explicit superclass \_\_init\_\_()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python-difference-between-super-init-and-expl)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using super with a class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817183/using-super-with-a-class-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cls.__base__.read` binds the `read` method explicitly to the base class. You should use `super().read` instead to bind the `read` method of the parent class to the current class.

Change:

```
return cls.__base__.read(fname0)
```

to:

```
return super().read(fname0)
```